# Django DateTime Subtraction Hours

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-models

I subtract two datetime objects and get integers instead of time in hours and minutes.

This is my MODEL.PY

```
class TimeLog(models.Model)
    start_date  = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True, default=datetime.now)
    end_date    = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True, default=datetime.now)
    time_diff = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

TimeLog.objects.filter(time_diff=None).update(time_diff=F('end_date') - F('start_date'))
```

I get `2020-09-12 22:51:58.383288 - 2020-09-12 23:03:57.088453 = 718705165`
How do I make `718705165` to be in hours and minutes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make `time_diff` a [**`DurationField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DurationField) to specify a *duration*, not a date time object:

```
class TimeLog(models.Model):
    start_date  = models.DateTimeField(null=True, auto_now_add=True)
    end_date    = models.DateTimeField(null=True, auto_now_add=True)
    time_diff = models.DurationField(null=True, blank=True)
```

You can use an [**`ExpressionWrapper`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/expressions/#expressionwrapper-expressions) to convert it to a `timedelta` object:

```
from django.db.models import DurationField, ExpressionWrapper, F

TimeLog.objects.filter(time_diff=None).update(
    time_diff=ExpressionWrapper(
        F('end_date') - F('start_date'),
        output_field=DurationField()
    )
)
```

Comment: Not working, This is from the documentation: Note

Arithmetic with DurationField works in most cases. However on all databases other than PostgreSQL, comparing the value of a DurationField to arithmetic on DateTimeField instances will not work as expected.

Comment: The solution works, Just had to change to postgres, thank you so much